# Independent identically distributed random, limit exists

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ be a sequence of iid $U(0,1)$ random variables. Prove that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\xi_1\xi_2\dots\xi_n}$$
>   exists with probability one. Find its value.

Watch this exercise [Independent, Identically Distributed Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723265/independent-identically-distributed-random-variables)

---

And I know that I should apply Borel-Cantelli (B-C), but my doubt is, I can write

> Let
>   $$E_n=\{\sqrt[n]{\xi_1\xi_2\dots\xi_n}<c,c\in\Bbb R$$
>   Then
>   $$P(E_n)=\int_n^{\infty} ?=\infty$$
>   and in that case, for B-C $P(E_n)=1$.
>   And its value, how do I calculate it?

Any idea to continue? please?

Comment: I suggest taking a logarithm and then using the strong law of large numbers

Comment: Why no reaction to the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Using Carmichael's hint in the comments, take the logarithm:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\sqrt[n]{\xi_1\xi_2\dots\xi_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\log\xi_i$$
This the mean of the $\log\xi_i$, and by the strong law of large numbers this will almost surely converge to the expected value of one $\log\xi_i$, which is $-1$ ($\log\xi_i$ is the negative of an exponential random variable with rate 1). Therefore, the original limit is almost surely $e^{-1}=\frac1e$.